# Get Minimum element from array then increase by 1 every time getMin() gets called

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given an sorted array = {1, 2, 3} provide getMin() method which returns minimum element and increment it by 1.

```
getMin(): return 1 and increment the min no by 1, array = {2, 2, 3}
getMin(): return 2 and increment the min no by 1, array = {3, 2, 3}
getMin(): return 2 and increment the min no by 1, array = {3, 3, 3}
getMin(): return 3 and increment the min no by 1, array = {4, 3, 3}
```

Any solution with time complexity O(1)?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: I tried solving using minHeap but that takes log n time complexity. Interviewer asked me to solve in O(1).

Comment: So find the minimum number and store the index. When you get to the end increment that index. Basic for loop. If it is presorted, you will know it is min when the number after it is larger.

Comment: That was a fun problem to solve.

Comment: @epascarello Could you please provide the implementation of getMin() method here?

Comment: @himanshukumar HashMap might be the catch here. Are you allowed to do some preprocessing before getMin() call?

Comment: @nice_dev Yes preprocessing are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two states for the array: either (1) the array is sorted, or (2) we have just incremented the first of a group of the smallest element.

If we have a smaller element ahead of a larger element, we increment the smaller element and maintain both (adjacent) pointers. If the next element is smaller, we advance both (adjacent) pointers; otherwise, move the pointers again to the start of the array since it is again sorted.

```
1 2 3
^ ^

2 2 3
^ ^

3 2 3
^ ^

3 3 3
^ ^

4 3 3
^ ^

4 4 3
  ^ ^
  
4 4 4
^ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

In addition to the sorted array, maintain a queue of integers (initially empty).

To implement the `getMin()` operation:

1. Take the smaller of next element in the array, or the element at the front of the queue.
2. Add 1 and put it at the end of the queue.

You may then notice that there are at most 2 different values in the queue at any time, so you can replace it with a few variables.